# MediaType should be application/schema+json to validate schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using justinrainbow/json-schema class to validate data against a schema.
However I'm receiving this error:

```
Media type application/schema+json expected
```

I could try to change ContentType in nginx for all my json files, but it doesn't make sense.

Another way would be to change the constant inside the library to 'application/json' (as my server is delivering for json files). Again, is not ok to change the source.

Is there a way to pass this as a parameter to justinrainbow/json-schema class?

https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for this because there is no content-type on the web as schema+json.

Just replace in justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Validator.php the SCHEMA_MEDIA_TYPE to 'application/json'.

You can also serve the file by local path, not by url.

Comment: Your comment might be more suitable as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now the library supports "json/application" additionally, but it throws an error at other content types.

To avoid this, you can extend the default "JsonSchema\Uri\UriRetriever" and override "[confirmMediaType()](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/blob/5.2.9/src/JsonSchema/Uri/UriRetriever.php)":

```
class MyUriRetriever extends JsonSchema\Uri\UriRetriever {

    public function confirmMediaType($uriRetriever, $uri) {
        return;
    }
}

$retriever = new \MyUriRetriever();

$refResolver = new JsonSchema\SchemaStorage($retriever);
$schema = $refResolver->resolveRef($schema);

$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator(new JsonSchema\Constraints\Factory($refResolver));
$validator->check($data, $schema);
```

$data: json decoded response from API

$schema: url of the schema

I had the same issue many times when testing other party`s API against their schema. Often they do not send the correct "Content-Type" header for their schemas and it can take long for them to change it.

### Update: Ability to exclude endpoints from validation

You can use [UriRetriever:addInvalidContentTypeEndpoint()](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/blob/5.2.9/src/JsonSchema/Uri/UriRetriever.php#L60):

```
$retriever = new UriRetriever();
$retriever->addInvalidContentTypeEndpoint('http://example.com/car/list');
```